# Nested group in Orbeon xforms

Tags: orbeon, xforms

Please anyone let me know if group within a group works in Orbeon xforms.

I have tried this but the inner group is not working.

The code might look like this:

```
<xforms:group ref=".[condition1]"> //outer group
...
...
            <xforms:group ref=".[condition2]"> //inner group
                           ...
                           ...
            </xforms:group>
...
...
</xforms:group>
```

Comment: Nested groups should work generally. Maybe it's a XPath issue. Does it work with an absolute XPath as condition? Could you give a complete example with instance data?

Comment: Hi tohuwawohu, thanks for responding. Please see my comment on the answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use groups within groups in XForms, and Orbeon Forms in particular. If you're having a problem with this, I suggest that you update your question with a full but minimal example that shows the issue, so we can further help with this.

Comment: Also, if you update to your question with an example, please post a quick comment here, so I am notified you did so.

Comment: Hi, Yeah, the nested groups works fine. I created a sample form and ran with xforms sandbox which worked fine. So it seems there is some issue with the xpath expression for my actual form. I will figure it out.

Comment: Good. And of course if you find a case where this doesn't work (whether you suspect a bug or something that could be wrong in your XForms), feel free to post another question here.